# How to pass id dynamically in jquery

Tags: jquery

I had array of div id i need to close all that div. i had used code below. not works. how to do this.

```
$.each([id_1, id_2], function(index, value) { 
  //alert(index + ': ' + value); 

$("#"+value).css({'display' : 'none'});

});
```

i need to pass id dynamically as `$("#"+id_value)`

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448924/getting-div-id-values-from-a-string-and-manupulating-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Array join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method as follows:

```
var idsInJquerySyntax = '#' + [id_1, id_2, id_3].join(', #');

$(idsInJquerySyntax).css({
 display: 'none'
});
```

You can see a working demo here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/qHVg7/

Answer (score 1):

Try passing them as strings? i.e.:

```
$.each(['id_1', 'id_2'], ...
```

You can also programattically build up a [Multiple Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) as others have suggested, but if you don't like the idea of having a 10,000 character long selector, and if your IDs already follow a naming convention (such as 'myid_1', 'myid_2', 'myid_10', etc.) then I would suggest using the [startsWith selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), like this:

```
$("[id^=myid]").hide(); // hide all elements with ID starting with 'myid'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just turn it into a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) via [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), like this:

```
$('#'+[id_1, id_2].join(',#')).hide();
```

This would basically be doing:

```
$('#someId1,#someId2').css({'display' : 'none'});
```

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) sets `display: none`, but in a way that [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) will restore it to the previous value.